# Délice et délices

Tags: genre

Le mot **délice** est semble-t-il masculin au singulier, et féminin au pluriel.

Je me demandais : quelle est l'origine de cette curiosité ? Est-ce que d'autres mots ont cette particularité ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les trois mots (que je connaisse) qui changent parfois de nombre en changeant de genre sont **amour**, **délice**, **orgue**.

Les trois mots sont d'origine latine et ont fluctué de genre à travers leur histoire, toutes les sources que j'ai consultées<sup>*</sup> ne disent pas exactement la même chose mais je pense qu'on peut se fier à ces citations du *Bon Usage* qu'on peut trouver [ici](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?t=30500) :

> Amours, délices et orgues sont masculins au singulier, et féminins au pluriel.
> *Le bon usage* : grammaire française de Maurice Grevisse (13e édition), consacre un chapitre aux "Noms changeant de genre en même temps que de nombre" et donne les raisons de ces subtilités.

> Extraits :

> 1/Amour au sens de "passion d'un sexe pour l'autre, passion charnelle" est ordinairement masculin au singulier et souvent féminin au pluriel (le pluriel pouvant être un synonyme emphatique du singulier.
> [...]
> Cependant, on trouve, soit dans une langue littéraire assez recherchée, soit dans l'usage populaire que reflètent d'autres textes littéraires, amour au féminin singulier, tandis que le masculin pluriel appartient à tous les niveaux de langue, même au niveau littéraire.
> [...]
> En dehors de ce sens, amour est presque toujours masculin, au singulier comme au pluriel.
> [...]
> Remarque : Quand les tours un de, un des, le plus beau des, et autres semblables, comportent le pluriel amours ("passion"), on met ordinairement au masculin les mots dont amours commande l'accord.

> Historique :
> — Amor était masculin en latin. — Amour avait les deux genres en ancien français, mais le féminin prédominait. Ce genre restait fréquent au XVIIe siècle, même en dehors du sens « passion » : Amour MATERNELLE, par exemple est chez CORN. (Rodog., V, 3) et chez RACINE (Phèdre. V, 5). — Pour Vaugelas (pp. 389-390), le mot était masculin quand il signifiait « Cupidon » et quand il était dit de l'amour de Dieu ; en dehors de ces deux cas, amour était indifféremment du masculin ou du féminin (mais ce dernier était jugé préférable). — Chez CORN., amour est féminin même lorsqu'il s'agit de l'amour des hommes pour Dieu (Pot., II, 6) ou de l'amour de Dieu pour les hommes (ib.. V, 3). — La différence de genre d'après le nombre, que les grammairiens ont voulu établir au XVIe et au XVIIe siècle, n'a jamais été appliquée rigoureusement dans l'usage. Notons Seulement ces exemples du masculin pluriel au XVIIIe siècle : Et mes PREMIERS amours et mes premiers serments (VOLT., Œdipe, II, 2). — Les plus CHARMANTS amours (MARIV., Père prudent et équitable, I, 1). — Des amours de voyage ne sont pas FAITS pour durer (J.-J. ROUSS., Conf.. PI., p. 254). — Je n'ai que des amours plus ou moins INTÉRESSANTS à vous conter, et point d'INTÉRESSÉS (prince de LIGNE, Contes immoraux, V). Etc.

> b/ Délice est masculin au singulier et féminin au pluriel.
> [...]

> Historique
> — Jusqu'au XVIe siècle, délice avait les deux genres, quel que soit le nombre, mais le masculin semble avoir été plus fréquent, même au pluriel. Les grammairiens (Vaugelas, lui, p. 249, rejetait le sing.) ont réglé l'usage du français d'après le latin, où l'on avait un nom féminin pluriel deliciae, et un
> nom neutre singulier delicium. L'usage a hésité longtemps : Tous les délices (MARIV., Journaux et œuvres div.. p. 18). — UNE délice (MAINTENON, Lettres. 18 avril 1701). — SA DERNIÈRE délice (CHAT., Mém., II, l, 6). —
> Même au XXe s., on trouve parfois délices au masculin : D'EFFRAYANTS délices (CAILLOIS, Chroniques de Babel, p. 44). — Autres exemples (où ce n'est pas phonétique) : BARRÉS, Dérac.. p. 56 ; ESTAUNIÉ, Tels qu'ils furent, p. 309 ; J. BURGOS, Pour une poétique de l'imaginaire, p. 206.

> c/ Orgue est masculin au singulier. Il est féminin au pluriel quand il désigne un seul instrument (pluriel emphatique : § 493, 6), mais il reste masculin quand il s'agit d'un véritable pluriel.
> [...]
> Historique
>
> - Orgue avait les deux genres au Moyen Age, avec prédominance de féminin. Le masculin s'est imposé (du moins au singulier) parce que le mot latin organum était neutre. Au XVIIIe siècle, on trouvait encore le féminin au singulier : Aussi fait-elle autant de bruit qu'UNE orgue de paroisse (MARIV., Journaux et oeuvres diverses, p. 284)

On pourra aussi consulter :
[La tradition : changement de genre au pluriel](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regle-orthographe/regle-accord-amours-delices-orgues-noms-masculin-singulier-feminin-pluriel/) sur Projet Voltaire.

[Amour, délice et orgue](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/QDL009) dans  le Dictionnaire de l'Académie française.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup> *Le bon usage* (Grevisse) ;  *Le Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* et *Le dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (les deux sld d'Alain Rey).</sup>

Comment: Gare aux orgues. Si l’on parle d’un seul instrument, mais que l’on utilise le pluriel, on parlera de grandes (par exemple) orgues, mais si l’on parle de plusieurs instruments, l’on parlera de grands orgues.

Comment: @Édouard: c'est dit explicitement : « Il est féminin au pluriel quand il désigne un seul instrument mais il reste masculin quand il s'agit d'un véritable pluriel ». Ou alors je ne comprends pas ce que tu veux dire.

Comment: C’est dit dans la cible du lien, je signale juste la difficulté supplémentaire ici. Parce qu’hélas, les liens ne sont pas éternels.

Comment: D'après le *Guichet du Savoir*, si je comprends bien, en plus des fluctuations de genre, ces trois mots ont eu au cours de l'Histoire les deux genres en même temps. Intéressante lecture, merci!

Comment: @arbautjc: Oui, c'est tout à fait ça, et aujourd'hui c'est fluctuant. Le genre de ces trois mots n'est pas gravé dans le marbre !